# ¿ Como hacer que los botones giren al pasar el ratón?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap, animación

Tengo unos botones los cuales quiero hacer tres veces mas grandes pero al intentarlo aumento la caja, pero no la figura.
Quería que cuando pase el ratón por encima, gire todo el boton 360º grados convirtiendo en un circulo.
Cuando quite el ratón vuelvan de nuevo a la forma que tienen ahora.
Tengo un ejemplo pero soy totalmente incapaz de emplearlo a este por mas vueltas que le di, parece sencillo, pero no he llegado mas que a lo que muestro en ejemplo.
Gracias.

```js
/*
Created by Alejandro Palacios https://github.com/AlexSoicalap
*/
$(function() {
 /*Define some constants */
 const ARTICLE_TITLE =  document.title;
 const ARTICLE_URL = encodeURIComponent(window.location.href);
 const MAIN_IMAGE_URL = encodeURIComponent($('meta[property="og:image"]').attr('content'));

 $('.share-fb').click(function(){
  open_window('http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u='+ARTICLE_URL, 'facebook_share');
 });

 $('.share-twitter').click(function(){
  open_window('http://twitter.com/share?url='+ARTICLE_URL, 'twitter_share');
 });

 $('.share-google-plus').click(function(){
  open_window('https://plus.google.com/share?url='+ARTICLE_URL, 'google_share');
 });

 $('.share-linkedin').click(function(){
  open_window('https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url='+ARTICLE_URL+'&title='+ARTICLE_TITLE+'&summary=&source=', 'linkedin_share');
 });

 $('.share-pinterest').click(function(){
  open_window('https://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url='+ARTICLE_URL+'&media='+MAIN_IMAGE_URL+'&description='+ARTICLE_TITLE, 'pinterest_share');
 });
 
 $('.share-tumblr').click(function(){
  open_window('http://www.tumblr.com/share/link?url='+ARTICLE_URL+'&name='+ARTICLE_TITLE+'&description='+ARTICLE_TITLE, 'tumblr_share');
 });

 function open_window(url, name){
  window.open(url, name, 'height=320, width=640, toolbar=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, location=no, directories=no, status=no');
 }
});
```

```css
/*
Created by Alejandro Palacios https://github.com/AlexSoicalap
*/

/*share row buttons*/
.share-buttons-row{
    height: 40px;

 display: -webkit-flex; /* Safari */
    -webkit-align-items: center; /* Safari 7.0+ */
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.share-buttons-row >div:hover {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    border-radius: 100px;
  }

.share-buttons-row > div {
 width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    cursor: pointer;

    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;

 text-align: center;
 float: left;
 margin-right: .3em;
 padding: 0;
 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 20px 20px;
}


.share-fb{
    background-color: #2d609b;
    background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
}

.share-twitter{
    background-color: #00c3f3;
    background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
}

.share-google-plus{
    background-color: #eb4026;
    background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
}

.share-linkedin{
    background-color: #0074a1;
    background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
}

.share-pinterest{
    background-color: #ca212a;
    background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
}

.share-tumblr{
    background-color: #36465d;
    background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>botones</title>
    </head>
 <body>
  
  <!-- Buttons, Copy this to your Page Article -->
  <div class="share-buttons-row">
   <!--Facebook's Button -->
   <div class="share-fb"></div>
   <!--Twitter's Button -->
   <div class="share-twitter"></div>
   <!--Facebook's Button -->
   <div class="share-google-plus"></div>
   <!--Linkedin's Button -->
   <div class="share-linkedin"></div>
   <!--Pinterest's Button -->
   <div class="share-pinterest"></div>
   <!--Tumblr's Button -->
   <div class="share-tumblr"></div>
  </div>
  

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Querés que la transición se haga de a poco? Porque ahora está girando 360º, pero como lo hace al instante no se ve. Si agregás `transform: rotate(360deg) scale(2);` vas a ver que el botón se agranda como un circulo y después vuelve a su estado normal.

Comment: @azeós gracias, pero si gira lo hace solo el contenedor, la figura que hay dentro no, y lo suyo es que girara todo. Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS:

```
.share-buttons-row > div {
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    ...
}
.share-buttons-row > div:hover {
    transform: rotate(360deg) scale(2);
    border-radius: 100px;
}
```

Con `transition` controlas el delay y la forma en la que se aplican todos los cambios.

https://jsfiddle.net/e1oemmqa/

Answer (score 5):

Para notar los cambios en un elemento podemos manipular cuanto tiempo dura una transición con la propiedad `transition` de css.

En tu caso solo necesitas agregar al `div` que quieres animar:

```
transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1.5);
transition: all .5s ease;
```

> NOTA: Para que la animación funcione correctamente tiene que agregarle las mismas propiedades pero con el valor inicial deseado ejemplo `transform: rotate(0deg)` y `scale(1)`.

**Transiciones de CSS**

> Las transiciones CSS, parte del borrador de la especificación CSS3, proporcionan una forma de animar los cambios de las propiedades CSS, en lugar de que los cambios surtan efecto de manera instantánea. Por ejemplo, si cambias el color de un elemento de blanco a negro, normalmente el cambio es instantáneo. Al habilitar las transiciones CSS, el cambio sucede en un intervalo de tiempo que puedes especificar, siguiendo una curva de aceleración que puedes personalizar.

```js
/*
Created by Alejandro Palacios https://github.com/AlexSoicalap
*/
$(function() {
 /*Define some constants */
 const ARTICLE_TITLE =  document.title;
 const ARTICLE_URL = encodeURIComponent(window.location.href);
 const MAIN_IMAGE_URL = encodeURIComponent($('meta[property="og:image"]').attr('content'));

 $('.share-fb').click(function(){
  open_window('http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u='+ARTICLE_URL, 'facebook_share');
 });

 $('.share-twitter').click(function(){
  open_window('http://twitter.com/share?url='+ARTICLE_URL, 'twitter_share');
 });

 $('.share-google-plus').click(function(){
  open_window('https://plus.google.com/share?url='+ARTICLE_URL, 'google_share');
 });

 $('.share-linkedin').click(function(){
  open_window('https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url='+ARTICLE_URL+'&title='+ARTICLE_TITLE+'&summary=&source=', 'linkedin_share');
 });

 $('.share-pinterest').click(function(){
  open_window('https://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url='+ARTICLE_URL+'&media='+MAIN_IMAGE_URL+'&description='+ARTICLE_TITLE, 'pinterest_share');
 });
 
 $('.share-tumblr').click(function(){
  open_window('http://www.tumblr.com/share/link?url='+ARTICLE_URL+'&name='+ARTICLE_TITLE+'&description='+ARTICLE_TITLE, 'tumblr_share');
 });

 function open_window(url, name){
  window.open(url, name, 'height=320, width=640, toolbar=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, location=no, directories=no, status=no');
 }
});
```

```css
/*
Created by Alejandro Palacios https://github.com/AlexSoicalap
*/

/*share row buttons*/
.share-buttons-row{
    height: 40px;

 display: -webkit-flex; /* Safari */
    -webkit-align-items: center; /* Safari 7.0+ */
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;

}
.share-buttons-row >div:hover {
    transform: rotate(360deg) scale(1.5);
    border-radius: 100px;
    z-index:10;
  }

.share-buttons-row > div {
 width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    cursor: pointer;

    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;

 text-align: center;
 float: left;
 margin-right: .3em;
 padding: 0;
 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 20px 20px;
    /*Nuevo codigo*/
    transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1);
    transition: all .5s ease;
    /*Nuevo codigo*/
}


.share-fb{
    background-color: #2d609b;
    background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
}

.share-twitter{
    background-color: #00c3f3;
    background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
}

.share-google-plus{
    background-color: #eb4026;
    background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
}

.share-linkedin{
    background-color: #0074a1;
    background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
}

.share-pinterest{
    background-color: #ca212a;
    background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
}

.share-tumblr{
    background-color: #36465d;
    background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>botones</title>
    </head>
 <body>
  
  <!-- Buttons, Copy this to your Page Article -->
  <div class="share-buttons-row">
   <!--Facebook's Button -->
   <div class="share-fb"></div>
   <!--Twitter's Button -->
   <div class="share-twitter"></div>
   <!--Facebook's Button -->
   <div class="share-google-plus"></div>
   <!--Linkedin's Button -->
   <div class="share-linkedin"></div>
   <!--Pinterest's Button -->
   <div class="share-pinterest"></div>
   <!--Tumblr's Button -->
   <div class="share-tumblr"></div>
  </div>
  

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

 </body>
</html>
```

### rotate()

> La función CSS rotate()  define una transformación para mover  un elemento alrededor de un punto fijo ( tal y como se especifica en la  propiedad transform-origin ) sin deformarlo. La cantidad de movimiento se define mediante un ángulo. Si es positivo, el movimiento serán en el sentido del reloj y, si es negativo, en sentido contrario al movimiento del reloj. Una rotación de 180° se llama punto de reflexión.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

### scale()

> La función CSS scale() define una transformación que modifica el tamaño de un elemento en el plano 2D. Debido a que la cantidad de escalado está definida por un vector, puede cambiar el tamaño de la dimensiones horizontal y vertical a diferentes escalas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Esta transformación de escalado se caracteriza por un vector bidimensional. Sus coordenadas definen cuanto escalamiento se realiza en cada dirección. Sí ambas coordenadas son iguales, la escala es uniforme (isotrópica) y la relación de aspecto del elemento se conserva (esta es una transformación homotética).
>
> Cuando un valor de coordenadas está fuera del rango [-1, 1], el elemento crece a lo largo de esa dimensión; cuando está dentro, se encoge. Si es negativo, el resultado es un reflejo de punto en esa dimensión. Un valor de 1 no tiene ningún efecto.

Comment: gracias, si marco una como respuesta, no puedo marcar la otra, como hago para marcar las dos, he repasado centro de ayuda y no veo como

Comment: @MiguelEspeso, efectivamente sólo puedes marcar 1 respuesta como aceptada. Puedes votarlas todas, sin embargo.

Comment: @MiguelEspeso ya le hice los cambios para acoplarlo a lo que buscas espero te ayude mejor saludos

Answer (score 2):

Te dejo un enlace a un jsfiddle con los cambios a tu código realizados:

https://jsfiddle.net/age9cd8j/

Esencialmente, he añadido un `scale(2)` al transform, `transition` para la escala, la rotación y el border-radius, y he subido el z-index al botón bajo el ratón para que quede mejor.

---

Edit: He añadido un cambio más después del comentario; ahora los iconos originales ocupan más espacio en su caja mediante un cambio en el "background-size" de 20px a 30.

Comment: Gracias, yo queria aumentar de tamaño cuando estan en su posicion natural, cuadrados, pero solo soy capaz de aumentar el contenido, la figura se que igual y queda muy feo. Pero con este efecto me has dejado alucinado. Gracias, ya buscare la forma de aumentar el tamaño inicial.

Comment: Verás que ahora he cambiado el "background-size" de 20px que le habías dado a 30px, lo cual efectivamente cambia el tamaño del icono original. Creo que esto es lo que quieres :).